# Using String.Contains() across multiple columns in EF6 model

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I feel like this is something simple and I'm just missing it...

Need to do a quick and dirty text search on FirstName and LastName columns together from a model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data:

```
FirstName            LastName
-------------------------------
John                 Appleseed
John                 Anderson
Chris                Cringle
George               Washington
```

Backend is SQL Server, using LINQ to Entities and Entity Framework 6, I need to do a lookup on the full name, but something like this won't work:

```
var results = from p in db.Persons
              where (p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName).Contains(keyword)
              select p;
```

LINQ doesn't like that.  This is for an autocomplete method; I want it to be able to find the results for "john a" if somebody types that -- it would be the first two rows from the sample data.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is going to end up making TSQL with a `LIKE` which means bad performance. If you have a lot of data and you need it to perform I'd suggest you create a calculated column for the concatenation and create a full text index upon it.

Comment: It's only a couple thousand rows. I'm fine with a LIKE statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF can only concat strings; it cannot concat characters.  Were it LINQ to Objects the `char` would be converted to a string without any problems, but EF just isn't robust enough to do that.  The fix is trivial enough though; use a literal *string*, not a literal character, for the space:

```
var results = from p in db.Persons
              where (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName).Contains(keyword)
              select p;
```

Comment: Oh my god, that was it. Just changing the ' to " did the trick. Can't believe I didn't try that. As I suspected, it was something simple.